# Proper path for client's "Local Group Policy" in PS' NetSecurity module

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall, group-policy

So, by default default, Windows client OSes (and servers too, to a degree) have 2 default Windows Firewall policies: weird `local firewall` and `local group policy`. In **netsh** you can easily switch between them:

```
netsh advfirewall set store gpo=COMUTERNAME
netsh advfirewall set store local
```

Default is always local.

What I can't figure out is what would be a proper path for local GPO in new cmdlets in powershell's "NetSecurity" module. The syntax is:

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName “Block Outbound Telnet” -Direction Outbound -Program %SystemRoot%\System32\tlntsvr.exe –Protocol TCP –LocalPort 23 -Action Block –PolicyStore domain\gpo_name`

(taken from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831755(v=ws.11)))

I've tried `COMPUTER\Local` and `COMPUTER\Local Group Policy` but no dice. There has to be a way to see what is the proper path/name for local GPO.

Answer (score 0):

`New-NetFirewallRule` has a lot of [options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for `-PolicyStore`, but to target the local host rules instead of a group policy object, just use either of these:

- `PersistentStore`: to add it to a section of the local firewall policy for custom rules. Rules created in this store are attached to the ActiveStore and activated on the computer immediately:

  ```
  New-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore PersistentStore
  ```
- `localhost`: (not the computer name) to add the rule to the local group policy:

  ```
  New-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore localhost
  ```
- `ActiveStore`: to target the currently active store (`Local` by default)

  ```
   New-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore ActiveStore
  ```

---

edit: I verified this command does create a rule in the local security policy:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name TestRule1 -DisplayName TestRule1 -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 5004 -Action Allow -Direction Inbound -PolicyStore localhost
```

You can view it with the same policystore

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName Test* -PolicyStore LocalHost
```

However, this rule created from powershell in the localhost policystore don't seem to attach automatically to the ActiveStore. `Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName Test* -PolicyStore ActiveStore` will show rules created from the secpol UI, but not rules created from powershell. Maybe requires a restart or a different param to enable?

Comment: `localhost: (not the computer name) to add the rule to the local group policy`

I've tried that already before asking the question: "New-NetFirewallRule: The network path was not found." I would not ask otherwise. For the record I did read already the docs on MS site

Comment: @Digika yes I think I misunderstood, my pc does not have the `gpo=computername` store. Can you try checking all your rules for the usable store name like this? `Get-NetFirewallRule | select policystoreSource,policystoreSourceType -Unique`. If the store is empty, you may need to create a rule with netsh first

Comment: I did not mean `gpo=computername` as literal, you replace it with your computer name, This only works in netsh. If you want to more context, here is example: open "Windows Firewall with Advanced..." from your start menu. Add any rule. Open "Local Security Policy", go to Windows Defender Firewall - do you see that rule? These are 2 different store/sources. `netsh` allows you to switch and add into either but for `*-NetFirewallRule` I cant figure out the correct network name/syntax.

Comment: If you add column "Rule Source" to the MMC panel you will see either "Local" or "Local Group Policy". The latter is what I want to access because by default `*-NetFirewallRule` adds to Local.

Comment: @Digika I do see what you mean now. I'm not sure why `localhost` returns that error to you though - it is the correct way to reference the local security policy gpo. I will add an example to my answer

Comment: Are you resting on client under any kind of domain/AD?

Comment: It does not attach because by default, on client, rules arent merged. You need to enable Rule Merging in GPO Firewall Settings. This does not answer why I cant add to localhost. Have to hit the MS answers board.

Comment: @Digika My client is on AD, Win10 ent, 21H2. I did see some people having the same issue, no real solutions. Maybe `-Verbose` may give you something? Are you also unable to read the policy store like `Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore LocalHost`?

Comment: Ah yes you have AD then it makes sense. Verbose does not make output more verbose. I decompiled a part of the ps module `Microsoft.Windows.Firewall.Commands.dll`  but it has no real logic. RIP. I wonder why `netsh works though`